# How to stop colgroup styles being overwritten by tr styles?

Tags: html, css, html-table, colgroup

Hi guys I have a table like that?

```
<table>

<colgroup>
    <col class="selected">
    <col>
</colgroup>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>lorem</td>
          <td>lorem</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and my styles are:

```
col.selected {
background-color: #f3f3f3; /*for selected column*/
}

table tbody tr:nth-of-type(2n+2){
background-color:#fafafa; /*zebra effect*/
}
```

all works great however the zerba style owerites col selection style. Any ideas how to avoid that so the selected column will be using style from col rather than nth child ?

Comment: Please add a working sample...

Comment: see the one above - 100% fully working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. The best work-around may to be dynamically render some CSS that highlights the correct column. To highlight the second column of a table, for example, you could use:

```
table tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
    background-color:red;  
}
```

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisPebble/tbLrv/

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine other than your col in the html doesn't have a selected class applied. Could this be your problem on the actual page (I relise you've only posted a code sample).

Comment: nope, this is done thorugh js etc but to avoid confusin i will update quetsion

Comment: also the code above is OK I know, but the thing is that col.selected style is being overwritten on nth rows and my questions is whether this can be avoided or no, thanks

Comment: A working example will help but remember that css is applied top down. Therefore, if both zebra and selection css applies to the col, your bottom css will win out.

Comment: not really, if you move down col.selected it won't help either

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the selector for the `zebra` background has a higher [**specificity**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) than the `col` selector.  Either give the `col` selector a higher specificity, or give the `tr` selector a lower one (or both).  If they're equal, order of rules in your CSS matters.

```
table colgroup col.selected {
    background-color: #f3f3f3; /*for selected column*/
} /* specificity: 13 */

table tr:nth-of-type(2n+2){
    background-color:#fafafa; /*zebra effect*/
} /* specificity: 12, will be overridden */
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is inaccurate. Your CSS only works because you've given the nth-row of even, which doesn't affect the first row anyway. If you change that to nth-of-type(odd) it immediately overrides the colgroup css. You can even !important the colgroup and it doesn't matter. I confess I don't know the complicated way in which the style is calculated for a cell, but I know that the tr/td generally overrides the colgroup,, regardless of the css. Certain corner cases do exist, but generally this just isn't possible.